# Custom sorting with MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting

I connect to Mongodb using the PECL PHP module Mongo. But I'm unable to find a solution to perform a custom server side sorting by passing an own Javascript function to the server.

```
$client = new \MongoClient( 'mongodb://localhost:27017', array() );
$collection = $client->selectCollection( 'mydata', 'users' );
$cursor = $collection->find( <my-query> );
$cursor->sort( <custom-sorting> );
```

In the Mongodb console this command works fine:

```
db.eval(
    function() {
        return db.users.find().toArray().sort(
            function( doc1, doc2 ) {
                return doc1.email < doc2.email;
            }
        ) 
    }
);
```

But I'm unable to pass such a sorting function to the server using the PECL module. I found nothing in the documentation until yet.

Comment: There is no inbuilt way of doing this currently, what you are doing there (same as aggregation framework) is pulling out all records and manually sorting in JS and then returning, you could emuklate with less stress on the db by doing it in PHP

Comment: Thanks for that info. I'll try to implement application side sorting. Do you have any experience with sorting on PHP side? How is the performance sorting e.g. 50.000 objects that way?

Comment: It will be quite fast, maybe about 40 microseconds

Comment: Basically you are sorting field `email` in descending order. Why not just use `->sort(array('email' => -1));` for that?

Comment: Thanks, but this was only an example. The needed sorting was more complex :)